# Run Ansible playbook from Cloud-Init

Tags: ansible, cloud-init

I have been learning Cloud-Init for several days to do an automatic deployment. To achieve this, and apply certain configurations, I am using Ansible playbooks. The problem that I have found is that I am not able to make the playbook run directly on the operating system that is being installed.

I leave you the user-data file that I am using.

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  
  version: 1

  identity:
    hostname: hostname
    password: "$6$cOciYeIErEet80Rv$YX8qt6vizXgcUkgIPSKD1qNZNxe77tSWOY3k/0.i8D8EpApaGNuyucxJvONmZiRj4rVM3L6EE4sLKcnzYVcMj/ "
    username: ubuntu
    
  storage:
    layout:
      name: direct
  
  locale: es_ES
  timezone: "Europe/Madrid"
  keyboard:
    layout: es
  
  packages:
    - sshpass
    - ansible
    - git

  late-commands:
    - git clone https://github.com/MarcOrfilaCarreras/dotfiles /target/root/dotfiles
    - ansible-playbook -i inventory-test /root/dotfiles/ansible/playbooks/docker.yml -u ubuntu -e "ansible_password=ubuntu" -e "ansible_become_pass=ubuntu"
```

PS: I am using Ubuntu Server 22.04, the Ansible command is temporary and only for testing and I know that I have to change the identity fields.

Comment: Can you add the logs of cloud-init in your question? What is the content of `inventory-test`? Where is this file coming from? (BTW, you could look at `ansible-pull`)

Comment: I second `ansible-pull` since you're manually doing a git clone first.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to configure localhost, it's better to use `local` transport (which is `-c local` in command line).

Basically, change ansible call to:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory-test /root/dotfiles/ansible/playbooks/docker.yml -c local
```

This will bypass all SSH things and run locally.

Answer (score 0):

Add a delay inside your cloudinit user data script.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ubuntu
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-pip -y
sudo pip3 install ansible
sleep 30 # wait for other dependencies the OS might be installing
sudo ansible-playbook init.yml
```

Use a longer sleep time first, then reduce it.